# Node JS Dust wont render new line

Tags: node.js, dust.js

I have file config.js that contains key - value pairs of text. This file is inserted into html by key. Example:

someKey : 'This is some text'

This is dust helper that inserts this text into html:

```
dust.helpers.translate = function(chunk, context, bodies, params) {
    chunk = config[params.key];
    return chunk;
};
```

I want to be able to insert new line but it is not working. Example:

someKey: 'This is some \ntext'

Any ideas?

Comment: NOTE: /n is ignored. When I put <br /> html looks like this: This is some <br />text

Answer (score 0):

You can either set the config flag to stop Dust from suppressing whitespace:

```
dust.config.whitespace = true
```

Or, you can insert a newline pragma in your template: `{~n}`

Since you are using a helper and inserting raw text, you probably want to do the first one.